# React native navigation 5 Authentication flows with Class-Components

Tags: reactjs, react-native, authentication, navigation

I migrate my React native app from the navigation version 4 to 5. I have some troubles because the whole migration guide works with Functional exemples but I use Class-Components. (And i'm not very comfortable with functional code)

I'm almost done, but I can't have the authentification process functional.
I try to follow this: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/auth-flow/
But I don't understand some parts.

What is the point to use reducer? :

```
 const [state, dispatch] = React.useReducer(
   (prevState, action) => {
     switch (action.type) {
       case 'RESTORE_TOKEN':
         return {
           ...prevState,
           userToken: action.token,
           isLoading: false,
         };
       case 'SIGN_IN':
         return {
           ...prevState,
           isSignout: false,
           userToken: action.token,
         };
       case 'SIGN_OUT':
         return {
           ...prevState,
           isSignout: true,
           userToken: null,
         };
     }
   },
   {
     isLoading: true,
     isSignout: false,
     userToken: null,
   }
 );
```

If it's to refresh the navigation when the userToken change, why don't we use useState?

And what is the point of `await AsyncStorage.getItem('userToken')` if we don't do `await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'dummy-auth-token')` before?

And I want to set the userToken in another file (auth.js)
Right now I do :
`await AsyncStorage.setItem('userToken', 'dummy-auth-token')` 
in my auth.js file. It works but I have to reload the app for the navigation to handle the change of userToken. How can I handle that properly.
Basically, I want to call the `SignInScreen()` function from another file but I can't figure out how...

Comment: Hi Any update on this are u able to solve this issue?

Comment: Nope... I put this in standby for now. I have a warning that say AsyncStorage is deprecated, so I guess there will be updates with a simpler method soon...